# Android onItemSelected - NullPointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

following code is throwing a *NullPointerException*:

```
public class test extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    private TextView explanation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.psqlpicker);

        explanation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.picker_explanation_text);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.picker_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new test());
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        explanation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.picker_explanation_text);
    }
}
```

It is thrown because of `explanation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.picker_explanation_text);` in the `onItemSelected(...)` method, but I have no idea why. It is, after all, working in the `onCreate(...)` method.

Comment: The actual line you've referred to is unlikely to throw a NPE; is the actual problem that its returning null and a NPE is thrown when explanation is referenced elsewhere?

Comment: No NPE is thrown when this line is removed. Once I put it in again, the NPE is thrown again. Something else is odd as well: "explanation" should be "filled" in the onCreate-method, it is still null in the onItemSelected-method however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new test());
```

use

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

You want to use your real activity as the target; you are creating a new object that is never initialized with a context so when it is called it crashes.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. I copied that from a tutorial and didn't put much thought into it. But it makes perfect sense, now it is working the way it should!